# Get data from $order on thank you page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout, orders, woocommerce-theming

I want to display a set of order details on the thank you page of my WooCommerce checkout. There are some already and I found them in the template `thankyou.php`.
But I need them in an extra `div` to add a tool called "Trusted Shops".

So I tried the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table', 'trusted_shops_thankyou', 15, 1 );
function trusted_shops_thankyou( $order_id ) {

    echo 'tsCheckoutOrderNr: '.$order->get_order_number();
    echo 'tsCheckoutBuyerEmail: '.$order->get_billing_email();
    echo 'tsCheckoutOrderAmount: '.$order->get_formatted_order_total();
    echo 'tsCheckoutOrderCurrency: '.$order->get_order_number();
    echo 'tsCheckoutOrderPaymentType: '.wp_kses_post( $order->get_payment_method_title());
    echo 'tsCheckoutOrderEstDeliveryDate: '.$order->get_order_number();

    // I need to fill the following DIVs
    echo '
        <div id="trustedShopsCheckout" style="display: none;">
            <span id="tsCheckoutOrderNr">2016-05-21-001</span>
            <span id="tsCheckoutBuyerEmail">mein.kunde@mail.de</span>
            <span id="tsCheckoutOrderAmount">4005.95</span>
            <span id="tsCheckoutOrderCurrency">EUR</span>
            <span id="tsCheckoutOrderPaymentType">VORKASSE</span>
            <span id="tsCheckoutOrderEstDeliveryDate">2016-05-24</span>
        </div>
        <div id="customCheckoutDiv"></div>
    ';
}
```

The problem is, that I don't get the data from `$order`.
I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_order_number() on null in....
```

I tried to add this code but it doesn't help:

```
global $woocommerce, $post;
$order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
```

What is missing? How could I get the data from `$order`?

And bonus: How could I get the estimated delivery date? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it!

I need to change that:

```
function trusted_shops_thankyou( $order_id )
```

to that:

```
function trusted_shops_thankyou( $order )
```